# helm install --set-file option does not extend the default values

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm

I have this **values.yaml** in my chart:

```
appConfig:
  spring:
    datasource: 
     ...
    cloud:
     ...
```

I want to extend these default values while installing/upgrading the release of this chart with another file **src/application.yaml**.

**src/application.yaml**

```
spring:
  datasource:
     ...
```

This is easy if the root object of this application.yaml is the same as values.yaml ( I mean "appConfig" by the root object).

In that case `helm install -f src/application.yaml` will be enough.

However, `src/application.yaml` must be merged with `appConfig` object.

I tried `--set-file` option as following:

```
helm install --set-file appConfig=src/application.yaml
```

Unfortunately, this option `--set-file` does not extend the object appConfig, instead, it totally override it.